# In Ember 2, I am unable to get the event object when binding on=keypress event to {{input}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

In Ember 2, I am trying to do probably the most simple thing. When I bind an event to an input element, I expect the event argument to be passed to my action handler but I am unable to get that. Simply I require to check for keyCode 13 which is for "enter" key on keyboard.

```
 {{input type=text
           value=model.filters.query
           placeholder="Search by title"
           action="search" onEvent="key-press"
 }}
```

My Function Handler is:

```
search(newValue){
 // I am only getting newValue and not the event object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM events are not exposed by default. [**Here is a issue regarding that**](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10574).

But for your use case we can trigger an action when the enter button is pressed by specifying the action in the 'enter' attribute of input helper. [**You can refer this**](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_input) which lists the different user events where an action can be added.

```
{{input 
  type=text
  value=query
  placeholder="Search by title"
  enter="search"
}}

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  query: '',
  actions: {
    search: function(value) {
      alert(value);
    } 
  }
});
```

[**Here is a working demo.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vemumi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)